# PHP getting linux file without permission?

Tags: linux, permissions, php

I have a PHP code, that list files and folders, using

```
shell_exec("sudo ls /home/user");
```

(www-data has sudo NOPASSWD access to ls. )

Now I need to read the file, where there is no guarantee, that the file has permissions for reading using www-data. I don't want to set permissions to 777. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking what permissions levels are required, or how to handle permissions errors in PHP, or ??

Comment: If you want your PHP code to be able to read the file, then the best thing to do is to put it somewhere other than `/home/user` as the user directories usually have 700 permissions. A better directory is `/opt` where the permissions are usually 755 or you can set them that way.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am asking, how to get them, if www-data doesn't have permission. I can do whatever in bash, or any commands in shell using shell_exec() in PHP by setting sudoers.

Comment: @NasirRiley I can probably copy the file from /home/user to /opt using bash script from shell_exec();

Comment: If you can't read it, then you can't copy it. That's why you're seeing the error.

Comment: @NasirRiley My question is, what is the most secure way to open the file in PHP without permissions. I know, I can't read the file without correct permissions. But I can set any reading command in bash, so I am asking for the most secure & convenient way to do that.

Comment: If the user running PHP that needs to read the directory doesn't have permissions, then it can't operate on it which includes reading them. The best thing that you can do is what has been suggested which is to to put it somewhere that the user can read it such as `/opt/directory`. The directories that are created there usually have 755 permissions and but if they don't you can set them so that the user has read access. If you just need to run `ls /opt/directory`, then just make sure that the permissions reflect that. If you need the user to read the files, set the permissions on those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a directory with three files as an example, …

```
-rw-------  1 root      root         9 Apr 29 15:35 bar
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  www-data   395 Apr 29 15:41 cat.php
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data     9 Apr 29 15:35 foo
```

…, a example cat.php could have the following output – which contains the php-skript itself for ovious reasons:

```
ERROR: cannot read file "bar"

echoing contents of file "cat.php":
---
<?php
$filenames = [];
exec('sudo ls -1 .', $filenames);

foreach($filenames as $filename) {
    if (!is_readable($filename)) {
        echo 'ERROR: cannot read file "' . $filename . '"' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }
    echo 'echoing contents of file "' . $filename . '":' . PHP_EOL . '---' . PHP_EOL;
    echo file_get_contents($filename);
    echo '---' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
---

echoing contents of file "foo":
---
I am foo
---
```